# Bind repeater item from resource value and data item

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I need to bind a label inside a repeater control using

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(... %>
```

but the Data item is contain the value not the text which should be present

So the case like

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CarCode")
```

and the car code will be "Frd1" for example, but it should show "Ford Edge" which stored in a resource file
with value "Frd1" So is there any way to retrieve the text value from the resource file direct in same line while binding

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by resource file but you can create a function on that page to look up a car's model from it's code and use that for data binding.

i.e.

```
protected string GetCarModelFromCode(string code)
{
    //Do look up here, say you store it as string carModel

    return carModel;
}
```

and then in your declarative code do:

```
<%# GetCarModelFromCode(Eval(Container.DataItem,"CarCode")) %>
```